# How to create a connection with google cloud instance with python code?

Tags: python, google-cloud-sql

I'm completely working on python and need to connect my instance of cloud SQL to my python project(sort of Software). Now what I need is that without using cloud_sql_proxy I need to make the connection only and only using python so that client need not need to install Google Cloud SDK.

used cloud_sql_proxy need a way to execute that without google SDK

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=Instance-Name:tcp:3306
```

I expect that without installing google SDK by only using python client can access the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do this:

1. Expose your cloudsql instance to the ip address that the python code runs on. Do this in the console under cloudsql -> Connections -> Authorized networks.
2. Connect via the ip address of the instance using your chosen database connection tool. Looking at your snippet, you are using postgres, so I would suggest `psycopg2`

Otherwise, if your python code is also running in GCP, you can use the internal ip (provided that they are in the same network)